# Use JavaScriptSerializer to convert Json to Xml

Tags: c#, javascriptserializer

How to convert json string to xml using JavaScriptSerializer?

Comment: Can't you convert with JSON.net?

Comment: I like to use in-build class to convert json to xml. While using JavaScriptSerializer (class)-deserializer method will return IDictionary<string,object>, using this is there is any other optimized way to convert it into XML.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert json to object with 
http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json
and object to xml with XMLSerializer